# ADFS Authentication with multiple account

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, openid-connect, adfs

I am authenticating user based on ADFS. I am adding claim provider trust to my adfs server so that I could use multiple accounts to login.
I am able to authenticate user for my adfs server whereas If I use other claim provider trust adfs to authenticate I am not able to return token

```
 app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {

                ClientId = clientId,
                //Authority = authority,  
                MetadataAddress = metadataAddress,
                RedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,

                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    AuthenticationFailed = context =>
                    {
                        context.HandleResponse();
                        context.Response.Redirect("/Error?message=" + context.Exception.Message);
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = context =>
                    {
                        string authorizationCode = context.Code;
                        // (tricky) the authorizationCode is available here to use, but...
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
            });
```

When I enter user credentials and hit login I get back to initial screen

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35295260/adfs-openid-connect-email-claim-and-external-adfs